Proposition 8.1 from Paolo Baldi's Stochastic Calculus book
I'm self-studying Paolo Baldi's book, and got really stuck on Proposition 8.1, which is about computing the differential of the product of two Ito processes. The proposition and proof is as below.


My first question is: when we first invoke Theorem 7.4 (theorem statement also included below) to show $\sup_{0\le t \le T} |X_{i, n}(t) - X_i(t)| \rightarrow 0$, don't we require $G_{i,n}$ and $G_i$ to be in $M^2$ instead of $M^2_{loc}$ (in the book, we only require $G_i$ to be in $M^2_{loc}$)?
My second question is: towards the end of the proof, how to use Theorem 7.4 (or Proposition 7.3, included below as well) to get the last two limits in probability? I got stuck on showing the requirement of Proposition 7.3.


Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!
